# How to send Stream Parameter to EMSDataSetResource

Tags: delphi, firebird, firemonkey, firedac, ems

I need to post a pdf file to a firebird database using Rad Server with a TEMSDataSetResource and am trying to send the file as a parameter.

I have created a simple table using Firebird 3.0 on Linux Ubuntu 18.04 with a text field and a Blob Binary Field.

The SQL in the qryPost is:

```
  insert into Table01 (FileName,FileData)
    values (:FileName,:FileData)
```

I created a sample that connects directly to the DataBase and the following code works to post the blobs. I have a full pot of coffee and will try again using EMSDataSetResource and post an update.

```
procedure THeaderFooterForm.btnGetAllClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  qryGetAll.Open('Select * From Table01');
end;

procedure THeaderFooterForm.btnPostClick(Sender: TObject);

var Stream:TMemoryStream;

begin
  qryPost.ParamByName('FileName').AsString := Edit1.Text;
  stream := TMemoryStream.Create;
  Try
    stream.LoadFromFile(edit2.Text);
    stream.Seek(0,0);
           qryPost.ParamByName('FileData').LoadFromStream(stream,ftBlob);
    qrypost.OpenOrExecute;
  Finally
    stream.Free;
  End;
end;

procedure THeaderFooterForm.SpeedButton1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if OpenDialog1.Execute then
    Edit2.Text := OpenDialog1.FileName
  else
    Edit2.Text := '';
end;
```

I am now adding a new project of a RAD Server Package. Create Package with Resource name of 'Blob' and as a Data Module with DataBase Endpoints and no Sample Endpoints. Select Connection to Database and Select Table01 and FINISH.

Same SQL

```
  insert into Table01 (FileName,FileData)
values (:FileName,:FileData)
```

and set param types both to ptinput and data types to ftstring and ftblob and set default param values. Execute the query at design time and it correctly posts string value to the blob field.

Separate issue and side note. I am using Rad Studio 10.3 and compiling the EMS server comes up with error that required package FireDacFBDriver not found. My work around is to remove FireDacFBDriver.dcp from the requires section of the project. Recompile and it asks to add the FireDacIBDriver which seems to work.

Here is the complete and amazingly short code for the EMS Server Package. All I changed is the ResourceSuffix name to 'Test'.

```
    unit Server_u;

// EMS Resource Module

interface

uses
  System.SysUtils, System.Classes, System.JSON,
  EMS.Services, EMS.ResourceAPI, EMS.ResourceTypes, FireDAC.Stan.Intf,
  FireDAC.Stan.Option, FireDAC.Stan.Error, FireDAC.UI.Intf, FireDAC.Phys.Intf,
  FireDAC.Stan.Def, FireDAC.Stan.Pool, FireDAC.Stan.Async, FireDAC.Phys,
  FireDAC.Phys.FB, FireDAC.Phys.FBDef, FireDAC.ConsoleUI.Wait,
  FireDAC.Stan.Param, FireDAC.DatS, FireDAC.DApt.Intf, FireDAC.DApt,
  EMS.DataSetResource, Data.DB, FireDAC.Comp.DataSet, FireDAC.Comp.Client;

type
  [ResourceName('Blob')]
  TBlobResource1 = class(TDataModule)
    FDConnection1: TFDConnection;
    qryTABLE: TFDQuery;
    [ResourceSuffix('Test')]
    dsrTABLE: TEMSDataSetResource;

  published
  end;

implementation

{%CLASSGROUP 'System.Classes.TPersistent'}

{$R *.dfm}

procedure Register;
begin
  RegisterResource(TypeInfo(TBlobResource1));
end;

initialization
  Register;
end.
```

Setting up the EMS client basically following this tutorial but using Firemonkey multi device.

http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Rio/en/Tutorial:_Implementing_a_FireDAC_RAD_Server_Client_Application

The resource on the EMSFireDacClient is set to 'blob/test/' and needs the trailing /

Dropped a TGrid and livebinding it to the memtable .

Had to modify SQL slightly since the EMSFireDacClient.getdata has to have data returned.

```
     insert into Table01 (FileName,FileData)
    values (:FileName,:FileData)
  returning Filename,FileData;
```

Tested on client with this procedure to make sure that it works and posts with string parameters.

```
    procedure THeaderFooterForm.btnPostClick(Sender: TObject);
var Stream:TMemoryStream;

begin
  EMSFireDacClient1.GetEndpoint.Params.Clear;
  EMSFireDacClient1.GetEndpoint.AddParameter('FileName',edit1.Text);
  stream := TMemoryStream.Create;
  Try
    stream.LoadFromFile(edit2.Text);
    stream.Seek(0,0);
    EMSFireDacClient1.GetEndpoint.AddParameter('FileData',Edit2.Text);
    EMSFireDacClient1.GetData;
  Finally
    stream.Free;
    mtblob.Refresh //refresh memtable
  End;
end;
```

All works well and this is where I am stuck. I can't figure out how to use a stream parameter with TEMSFireDacClient.

There is no Loadfromstream for params, only addparameter which takes only string value. Some setstream procedure on parambyname but doesn't seem to work and posts the text value. Here is what I tried and I am stumped.

```
    procedure THeaderFooterForm.btnPostClick(Sender: TObject);

var Stream:TMemoryStream;

begin
  EMSFireDacClient1.GetEndpoint.Params.Clear;
  EMSFireDacClient1.GetEndpoint.AddParameter('FileName',edit1.Text);
  stream := TMemoryStream.Create;
  Try
    stream.LoadFromFile(edit2.Text);
    stream.Seek(0,0);
    EMSFireDacClient1.GetEndpoint.AddParameter('FileData',edit2.Text);
    EMSFireDacClient1.GetEndpoint.Params.ParameterByName('FileData').SetStream(stream,ooCopy);
    EMSFireDacClient1.GetData;
  Finally
    stream.Free;
    mtblob.Refresh //refresh memtable
  End;
end;
```

This seems the correct way to add and access the second param but still no luck. It runs and posts the text field but nothing to the blob field.

```
    procedure THeaderFooterForm.btnPostClick(Sender: TObject);

var Stream:TMemoryStream;
    aParam: TRESTRequestParameter;

begin
  EMSFireDacClient1.GetEndpoint.Params.Clear;
  EMSFireDacClient1.GetEndpoint.AddParameter('FileName',edit1.Text);
  stream := TMemoryStream.Create;
  Try
    stream.LoadFromFile(edit2.Text);
    stream.position := 0;
    aParam := EMSFiredacClient1.GetEndpoint.Params.AddItem;
    aParam.Name := 'FileData';
    aParam.SetStream(stream,ooCopy); //also tried ooRest and ooApp
    EMSFireDacClient1.GetData;
  Finally
    //stream.Free;
    mtblob.Refresh //refresh memtable
  End;
end;
```

I am stumped. Do I need a different approach sending file in header or body of Rest request, but then what do I do on the server side. I can't find any examples at all of the EMSDataSetResouce with blob fields. Thanks for any help.

Comment: Welcome to SO! When you place a question try to add a minimum content: input sample, expected output sample, what did you try, research and where are you stacked. What did you try?

Comment: Thanks. I will post more detail starting with posting a .pdf blob directly to Firebird using Firemonkey and FireDac. Is it an omen how many F Words that is :-}

Answer (score 0):

So I accomplished uploading the pdf as a blob using entirely the EMSDataSetResource with a database endpoint. My difficulty had been getting the blob properly into the client side memtable. So here is what worked.

Create the Server Side Package but leave the SQL as created.

```
select * from TABLE01
```

Set up the client using the above Embacadero Tutorial.

Retrieve the data with the simple

```
EMSFireDacclient1.GetData;
```

Append a new record to the FDMemTable

```
procedure THeaderFooterForm.AppendButtonClick(Sender: TObject);

var
  aStream:TMemoryStream;
begin
  mtblob.Append;
  mtblob.FieldByName('filename').AsString := edit1.Text;
  aStream := TMemoryStream.Create;
  try
    aStream.LoadFromFile(edit2.Text);
    aStream.Position := 0;
    (mtblob.FieldByName('filedata') as TBlobField).LoadFromStream(aStream);
  finally
    mtblob.Post;
    aStream.Free;
  end;
end;
```

And send the updates to the server

```
procedure THeaderFooterForm.UpdateButtonClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  emsfiredacclient1.PostUpdates;
end;
```